# Qmail SMTP Whitelist & SMTP Authentication?

Tags: smtp, authentication, email, whitelist

How can I get qmail to work with both an smtp whitelist and smtp authentication?

If my IP is whitelisted, SMTP authentication does not seem to work (error: "the server does not support SMTP password authentication). This is particularly annoying when using our SMTP server on a roaming device, eg. an iPhone.

As soon as the iPhone is not using the whitelisted IP (ie. not in the office, but over 3G), then SMTP authentication works fine.

Comment: _How can I get qmail to work_  - try using supported software...?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite understand what you mean by that? Perhaps I should say, how can I use SMTP Authentication and an SMTP whitelist with qmail?

Comment: I'll be more explicit - by not using qmail.  It did well for its day, but it's now old, unsupported, and missing lots of useful features.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean; unfortunately at this point we do not have a choice at this time :(

Answer (score 1):

If you have the option, install something specifically as a [*Mail Submission Agent*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_submission_agent) (MSA) for authenticated SMTP mail submission listening on port 587, and have that forward mails to your qmail MTA for subsequent delivery.